# If $S_2$ is a covering space of $T_2$,then the sheets of $S_2$ is infinite

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why if there is a covering map $p$ maps $S_2$ to $T_2$, $T_2$ is the torus. then the sheets of  $p$ is infinite?, that is for all $b\in T_2 $, $p^{-1}(b)$ has infinite elements.Using the result  we have a contradiction by the compactness of $S_2$,which proves that $S_2$ is not a covering space of $T_2$.

Comment: I voted to close you question. It is completely unclear what you want toi ask. Is $S_2$ a specific covering of the torus? If yes, which? If you mean any covering, why should it be compact? And why should there be a contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $S^2$ covers $T^2$, pick a base point $b\in T^2$ and one of its lifts $a\in p^{-1}(b)\subseteq S^2$. Given a loop $\gamma$ in $T_2$ (defined as a function $\gamma:[0, 1]\to T^2$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$) starting at $b$, it will lift to a path $\gamma'$ in $S^2$ starting at $a$ and possibly looping back to $a$.

If $\gamma'(1) = a$, then $\gamma'$ is a loop in $S^2$, and therefore null-homotopic. So $\gamma$ is nullhomotopic in $T^2$. Which by contrapositivity means that if $\gamma$ is non-null-homotopic in $T^2$, then  $\gamma'$ is a non-loop path in $S^2$, with $\gamma'(0) = a\neq \gamma'(1)$.

We have $\gamma'(0) = a = a_1$ and $\gamma(1) = a_2\in p^{-1}(b)$. Now do $\gamma$ twice in succession to get $\gamma^2$ and lift that to $S^2$. $(\gamma^2)'$ now becomes a path from $a$ to $a_3\in p^{-1}(b)$. Repeat ad infinitum.

If there are ever any repeats among these points, say $a_i=a_j$ with $i<j$, then $(\gamma^{j-i})'$ is a loop in $S^2$ and therefore $\gamma^{j-i}$ is null-homotopic in $T^2$. So if $\gamma$ starts out as non-null-homotopic, there can be no such repeats (I assume we already know the fundamental group of the torus). Which proves that $p^{-1}(b)$ has infinitely many points.

Answer (score 2):

For nice spaces like these and for any finite $n$, the Euler characteristic of an $n$-sheeted covering space is $n$ times the Euler characteristic of the base space. So for $S^2$ covering $T^2$ we'd have $2=n\cdot0$.